# Salesforce Query File ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, salesforce

I am trying to get the name of files saved inside a salesforce object. I do this query:

```
const files = await this.conn.sobject('ContentDocumentLink').find({
            LinkedEntityId: documentId,
            ShareType: 'V'
})
```

it provides me with :

```
  {
    attributes: {
      type: 'ContentDocumentLink',
      url: '/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/ContentDocumentLink/xxxxxxxxx'
    },
    Id: 'xxxxxxxxx',
    LinkedEntityId: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    ContentDocumentId: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    IsDeleted: false,
    SystemModstamp: '2022-02-24T12:03:04.000+0000',
    ShareType: 'V',
    Visibility: 'AllUsers'
  }
```

But all I have are the unique IDs of each file. I need the file names as well. How do I then query to populate and get the file name as well?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to perform SOQL Query to retrieve the name of the file.

```
this.conn.query("SELECT contentdocument.title FROM ContentDocumentLink where ContentDocumentId = 'SOME_FILE_ID'", function(err, result) {
  if (err) { return console.error(err); }
  console.log("result : " + result);
});
```